# ASPxGridView - "parameter name: index" error

Tags: c#, devexpress

Does anyone know what does means "parameter name: index" error while performing callback on the `aspxgridview`? When I run the `grid.PerformCallback()` command, I see this error.

Note: my callback function

```
protected void grid_CustomCallback(object sender, DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridView.ASPxGridViewCustomCallbackEventArgs e)
{
    grid.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: Since you are doing custom callback have you tried to set `EnableSynchronization property to False`

Comment: ASPxGridView doesn't have `EnableSynchronization` property

Comment: Can you show us the full error message?

Comment: I have an error messagebox from webpage. **Parameter name: index** @Jason

Comment: @erdincozdemir Plase show us your full code and full error message in your question.

Answer (score 3):

May be a little late for OP but what solved this for me was to set `EnableSynchronization = false` for the control that I was adding items in through javascript.

Clarification:

I was adding items to a combobox through the `cbFormattingOption.InsertItem(i, v);` method. Setting EnableSynchronization to false false for that combobox solved this issue.